# Qt5.4.1 + QtMultimedia + Raspbian

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml, raspbian, qtmultimedia

I have a problem with showing video using QtMultimedia on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian):

When I'm using QMediaPlayer + QVideoWidget it gives me an error: "this plugin doesn't support setParent"

When I'm trying to show video with QtQuick it gives me errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/QtApp $ ./JM
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and
QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).
GStreamer; Unable to pause - ""
Error: "No URI set"
```

Here is QtQuick project: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e41fa0721bc895d7fe00

Video is placed here: /home/pi/Desktop/QtApp/video/adv.mov

How can I solve this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not find your video.
Replace:

```
source: "./video/adv.mov"
```

with:

```
source: "file:///home/pi/Desktop/QtApp/video/adv.mov"
```

in your video.qml

You added your video.qml into the Qt resources:

```
app.load(QUrl("qrc:/qml/video.qml"));
```

This is practically a different file system, so your root folder is probably not what you expected... and your relative path points nowhere.